# Week number and Week day

Tags: php, date, formatting

I have week number of current year and week day generated by date() like this.

```
$week_number = date('W');
$week_day = date('w');
```

I need to format this. How can I get starting date of this week? Or day of month with $week_number and $week_day?

Comment: What do you mean by starting date? The preceding Monday, or Sunday?

Comment: No sorry for poor explanation. I need to convert week number to something like this. 1-7 March

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

Maybe [this article](http://derickrethans.nl/calculating-start-and-end-dates-of-a-week.html) helps you. It describes how to get the start and end date of a given week.

```
<?php
// Monday
echo date(
    datetime::ISO8601,
    strtotime("2006W37"));

// Sunday
echo date(
    datetime::ISO8601,
    strtotime("2006W377"));
?>
```

Where the format is `<year>W<week-number><daynumber>` and Monday is `1`.

**Update 2:**

Maybe another possibility is to use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) this way:

```
echo strtotime("last Monday");
echo strtotime("next Sunday");
```

You can combine this with `date()` to get the date in the desired format.

---

You can get the day of the month with `date('d')` directly.

[`date()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php).

Comment: I know this function, but I get current day, I need get day of with given week number and week day.